# Weak convergence on uniformly convex Banach spaces

Tags: convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

I want to prove the following:

Let X be a uniformly convex Banach space, $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subset X, x \in X, \|x_n\| \to \|x\|$, $x_n$ converges weakly to $x$.
Then $x_n$ also converges strongly to $x$.

Actually I have not really an idea how to do this.

Would be grateful for some tips!

S

---

I mean what I have is, that $ < f, x_n -x> \to 0$ $\forall f \in X^*$ and $\|x_n\| \to \|x\|$.

And $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0 \forall x,y \in X, \|x\|,\|y\| \leq 1: \|x-y\|\geq\epsilon \Rightarrow \frac{\|x+y\|}{2} \leq 1-\delta $

or $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0 \forall x,y \in X, \|x\|,\|y\| \leq 1:\frac{\|x+y\|}{2} > 1-\delta \Rightarrow  \|x-y\| < \epsilon $.

And I want to show that $\|x_n-x\|\to 0$.

My first idea was that I want to have somehow $\|x_n-x\|<\epsilon$. So I need to fulfill the condition of the uniformly convexness?

---

EDIT - Possible Solution:

Let $\epsilon > 0$ arbitrary. As $X$ is a uniformly convex Banach space there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for every $x,y \in X$ with $\|x\|,\|y\|\leq 1: \frac{\|x+y\|}{2} > 1-\delta$ implies $\|x-y\|<\epsilon$.

Let $f\in X^*$ such that $f(x)=\langle f, x\rangle = \|x\|$ and $\|f\|_* = 1$.

Then we have $\frac{\|x_n+x\|}{2} = \frac{\|f\|_{*}\|x_n+x\|}{2} \geq \langle f,\frac{x_n+x}{2}\rangle \to \langle f,x\rangle = \|x\| = 1 > 1-\delta$.

So $\|x_n-x\| < \epsilon$.

As $\epsilon$ was arbitrary $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges strongly to x.

But then I didn't use that $\|x_n\| \to \|x\|$.

Comment: You are right. I changed that in the question. I would like to stress that I don't want to have a complete solution or something like that, just some "thrust in the right direction"

Comment: I wrote out a full answer, then read your comment. I've deleted the answer, but it can be undeleted if you want to read it. My hints would be: argue that you can assume without loss of generality that $\|x_n\| = \|x\| = 1$, and use the fact that $X \setminus B[0; 1 - \delta]$ is a weakly open neighbourhood of $x$.

Comment: So the idea is to show that for every $\epsilon$ whatever its $\delta$ is there is an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{\|x_n+x\|}{2}>1-\delta$?

Comment: Note also that $\frac{x_n + x}{2} \rightharpoonup x$ as well. So, eventually $\frac{\|x_n + x\|}{2} > 1 - \delta$. P.S. if you want to notify me that you've left a comment, you can put @TheoBendit into the comment.

Comment: @TheoBendit: so can I say $\frac{\|x_n+x\|}{2} = \frac{\|f\|_{*}\|x_n+x\|}{2} \geq \langle f,\frac{x_n+x}{2}\rangle \to \langle f,x\rangle = \|x\| = 1 > 1-\delta?$ where $f\in X^*$ such that $f(x)=\langle f,x\rangle = \|x\|$ and $\|f\|_{*} = 1$

Comment: @TheoBendit I updated my Question with my solution. Can you say, if it is right or what I did wrong?
Why can I say without loss of generality that $\|x_n\|=\|x\|=1$?

Comment: You need to deal with $\|x\| = 0$ case first, and the $\|x_n\| \to \|x\|$ condition gives you strong convergence. Otherwise, changing $x_n$ to $x_n / \|x\|$ will make the limit $x / \|x\|$, so without loss of generality, $\|x\| = 1$. Next, try rescaling $x_n$ to $x_n / \|x_n\|$. Note that for any functional, we have $f(x_n / \|x_n\|) = f(x_n) / \|x_n\| \to f(x) / \|x\| = f(x)$, hence $x_n / \|x_n\| \to x$. Thus, without loss of generality, $\|x_n\| = 1$ for all $n$ too. You need these assumptions so that you can apply uniform convexity.

Comment: Then, using your argument with the rescaled $x$ and $x_n$, you can then conclude that, in terms of the original $x$ and $x_n$, that $x_n / \|x_n\|$ converges to $x / \|x\|$ strongly, and hence $x_n$ converges to $x$ strongly.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TheoBendit
Your last two comments are pretty obvious. Don't know, why I didn't figure it out by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $X$ is uniformly convex, $x_n \overset{\text{weakly}}{\longrightarrow} x$ and $\| x_n \| \longrightarrow \| x\|$.

Now let $y_n = \frac{x_n}{\|x_n\|}$ and $y = \frac{x}{\|x\|}$. Then we have $\| y_n \| = 1$ and $\| y \| = 1$ and also $y_n \overset{\text{weakly}}{\longrightarrow} y$ and $\| y_n \| \longrightarrow 1$. Now, by Hahn-Banach, take $f \in X'$ with $\| f \| = 1$ and $|f(y)| = 1$. Then we get, due to weak convergence: $|f(y_n)| \longrightarrow 1$. Therefore, we obtain $\left|\frac{f(y_n) + f(y)}{2}\right| \longrightarrow 1$ and also $\left|\frac{f(y_n) + f(y)}{2}\right| \leq \| f \| \left\| \frac{y_n + y}{2} \right\| = \left\| \frac{y_n + y}{2} \right\| \leq 1$. By the sandwich principle, we have that $\left\| \frac{y_n + y}{2} \right\| \longrightarrow 1$. Now, uniform convexity of $X$ implies that $\| y_n - y \| \longrightarrow 0$, meaning $y_n \longrightarrow y$ and due to $\| x_n \| \longrightarrow \| x \| $, we obtain that $x_n \longrightarrow x$.